# How to properly bind an ObservableCollection inside an ObservableCollection to an ItemsControl (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, observablecollection

Before I start with the explanation of the problem, I am new to WPF and I still did not grasp every concept behind the MVVM pattern.

I have an `ObservableCollection<Vertex>`, where `Vertex` is a class representing a vertex in a graph. It contains properties representing its position: X,Y and `Point` Position. It also contains an `ObservableCollection<Edge>` where `Edge` is a simple model containing 2 Vertices (From and To) and its weight as an int.

My intention is to display both the collection of vertices (as ellipses) and then also display the edges as lines. The view I am trying to create should allow for addition of these vertices and edges, which I am doing through commands since I am trying to follow the MVVM architecture.

The vertices can be added without any problems, however the problems start when I am trying to add an edge from one vertex to another. The first selected vertex for the edge gets moved to a completely different spot on the view (+ on both x and y axis) and the line representing the edge has the correct slope, but also moved somewhere else.

Here is a brief demonstration of what I mean:
[Situation before the addition of an edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGmaY.png)
[Situation after the addition of an edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEuvV.png)

This is what I currently have in the xaml file for the view with the canvas (only the important part with the ItemsControl):

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Graph.Vertices}" Background="AliceBlue">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <commands:MouseBinding Command="{Binding CanvasClickCommand}"></commands:MouseBinding>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True">
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10">
                            <Ellipse.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Ellipse.Style>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Edges}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Path Stroke="Black" >
                                        <Path.Data>
                                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding FromVertex.Position}" EndPoint="{Binding ToVertex.Position}" />
                                        </Path.Data>
                                    </Path>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And this is what I have in the ViewModel file for this:

```
public class SceneEditorViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private enum Mode
        {
            VertexAdditionMode,
            EdgeAdditionMode,
            ViewMode,
            VertexDeletionMode
        }

        private readonly SceneEntry _sceneEntry;

        private Mode _mode = Mode.ViewMode;
        private Vertex? _firstClickedVertex;
        public IGraph Graph => _sceneEntry.Graph;

        /// <summary>
        /// Commands for Buttons
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand LoadFileCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SetNameCommand { get; }
        public ICommand BackCommand { get; }
        public ICommand AddVertexCommand { get; }
        public ICommand AddEdgeCommand { get; }
        public ICommand ClearCommand { get; }
        public ICommand DeleteVertexCommand { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Command called after user clicks on the canvas area
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand CanvasClickCommand { get; }
        public string NameTextBox
        {
            get => _sceneEntry.Name;
            set
            {
                _sceneEntry.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public SceneEditorViewModel(NavigationManager navigationManager, SceneEntry? entry = null)
        {
            LoadFileCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadFile, o => true);
            SetNameCommand = new RelayCommand(SetName, o => true);
            BackCommand = new NavigationCommand<SceneMenuViewModel>(new NavigationService<SceneMenuViewModel>(navigationManager, 
                () => new SceneMenuViewModel(navigationManager)));
            AddVertexCommand =
                new RelayCommand(
                    o => _mode = _mode == Mode.VertexAdditionMode ? Mode.ViewMode : Mode.VertexAdditionMode,
                    o => true);
            AddEdgeCommand =
                new RelayCommand(
                    o => _mode = _mode == Mode.EdgeAdditionMode ? Mode.ViewMode : Mode.EdgeAdditionMode,
                    o => true);
            CanvasClickCommand = new EventRelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(OnMouseDown, o => true);
            DeleteVertexCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteVertex, o => true);
            _sceneEntry = entry ?? new SceneEntry("", SceneMenuViewModel.SceneIdCounter++, new Graph());
            ClearCommand = new RelayCommand(o => _sceneEntry.Graph.Vertices.Clear(), o => true);
            if (entry is null)
            {
                App.Scenes.Add(new SceneEntryViewModel(navigationManager, _sceneEntry));
            }
        }

        private void LoadFile(object obj)
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Graph files (*.graph)|*.graph"
            };
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                var file = openFileDialog.FileName;
                var serializer = new GraphSerializer();
                var graph = serializer.Deserialize(file);
                _sceneEntry.Graph = graph;
            }


            //var serializer = new Serializer();
            //var graph = serializer.Deserialize(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
            //_graphViewModel.Graph = graph;
        }

        private void SetName(object obj)
        {
            if (NameTextBox != "")
            {
                _sceneEntry.Name = NameTextBox;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteVertex(object obj)
        {
            _mode = _mode == Mode.VertexDeletionMode ? Mode.ViewMode : Mode.VertexDeletionMode;
        }
        private void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = e.Source as IInputElement;
            var position = e.GetPosition(sender);
            switch (_mode)
            {
                case Mode.VertexAdditionMode:
                    var vertex = new Vertex("", position.X, position.Y, new ObservableCollection<Edge>());
                    _sceneEntry.Graph.AddVertex(vertex);
                    break;
                case Mode.EdgeAdditionMode:
                    var first = _sceneEntry.Graph.Vertices.FirstOrDefault(v =>
                        v.X - 10 < position.X && position.X < v.X + 10 && v.Y - 10 < position.Y &&
                        position.Y < v.Y + 10);
                    if (first is null) break;
                    if (_firstClickedVertex is null )
                    {
                        first.IsSelected = true;
                        _firstClickedVertex = first;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (first != _firstClickedVertex)
                        {
                            var edge = new Edge()
                            {
                                FromVertex = new Vertex(_firstClickedVertex),
                                ToVertex = new Vertex(first),
                                IsDirected = false,
                                Weight = 1
                            };
                            _sceneEntry.Graph.Vertices.First(v => v == _firstClickedVertex).Edges.Add(edge);
                        }
                        _firstClickedVertex.IsSelected = false;
                        _firstClickedVertex = null;
                    }
                    break;
                case Mode.VertexDeletionMode:
                    var selected = _sceneEntry.Graph.Vertices.FirstOrDefault(v =>
                        v.X - 10 < position.X && position.X < v.X + 10 && v.Y - 10 < position.Y &&
                        position.Y < v.Y + 10);
                    if (selected is null) break;
                    _sceneEntry.Graph.Vertices.Remove(selected);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

The code is really messy (mainly due to trying to figure out what is the exact problem), but the intention should be somewhat visible.

The Graph class is basically just a class encapsulating the ObservableCollection and all of the models implement INotifyPropertyChaned interface.

Am I on the right path with this approach inside of the xaml file or is there a much better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if your view model classes don't need a UI (anything rendered), input devices like mouse or keyboard or a user to function, then you are correctly following the design rules imposed by the MVVM design pattern. Your view model class relies on UI (the OpenFileDialog) and on input devices (mouse event handling). Therefore, your code does not comply with the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: The `ItemsControl` will arrange its item containers vertically stacked unless you define a different host panel. To properly place the objects on the screen, you have to add them to the same `Canvas`. A simple solution to achieve this is to make use of polymorphism: give `Vertex` and `Edge` a common base type e.g. `GraphObject` and add them to the same collection and bind this collection to a single `ItemsControl`. Then simply arrange all objects on the common item container host (the `Canvas` panel).

Comment: You basically have to flatten the data structure to remove the hierarchy. The hierarchy is only abstract, meaning that their relationship expressed by the data models (how they are linked to each other).

Comment: If you want to maintain your current data structure, I recommend extending `ItemsControl` and implementing the building of the visual graph in this new type.

Comment: In fact, your data structure doesn't have to and shouldn't be hierarchical at all. You should have a simple collection of edges (lines) that are position based on their attributes.